# Trigger/Emit vue event from Cypress e2e test

Tags: vue.js, cypress, e2e-testing

I am using Cypress to test user journeys on a VueJs webapplication. This is an End2End test. The tests run on a dedicated VM at regular intervals and is not part of the frontend codebase (Not part of CI/CD of the frontend code. Since the cypress tests are in a different codebase, I cannot do component loading etc.,).

I need to test the functionality of swapping an item. On the item swap page, you scan the QR Code of the new item. On a successful scan, I emit an event(with decoded data) so that the listener can then fetch details of the scanned item such as the expiry date, Lot no etc. These details are essential and decides whether the swap button is enabled or not.

I am unable to test this qr scan part using cypress.

Here is a simple picture of how the user journey for swapping is [image: how swap works]

I use [Vue-QR-Reader V 3.1.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-qrcode-reader/v/3.1.0) (Vue2) for the QR code decoding.

I have looked into the [vue-qrcode-reader](https://github.com/gruhn/vue-qrcode-reader/blob/v3.1.0/src/components/QrcodeStream.vue#L17) library and tried to render an image on the canvas (in the cypress test) and see if the library can pick it up - but has not helped.
I am gonna try with a video too.

If I can send a custom vue event from the cypress test it would be amazing (could not find a way to do it).

I feel that this is a lot of hassle to test this particular user journey. I feel that there has to be a simpler way to do this test.

I am open to ideas of how I can test this.

Comment: Probably mock camera api based on the lib's expectations? https://github.com/gruhn/vue-qrcode-reader/blob/v3.1.0/src/misc/camera.js#L35